# How to replace row with float values with in a nested numpy array with a row of `NaN`s?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, nan

Say i have a numpy array:

```
a=np.array([[7,2,4],[1.2,7.4,3],[1.5,3.6,3.4]])
```

And my goal is to replace rows that which contain floats with a row of `NaN`s, and so far this is my attempt:

```
a[a.dtype==float]=np.nan
```

Which works, but only the first row that should be `NaN`, there's an second row that should be `NaN` that's left alone.

So my desired output would look like:

```
[[ 7.   2.   4.]
 [ nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan]]
```

Comment: Think : `a=np.array([[7,2,4.0],[1.2,7.4,3],[1.5,3.6,3.4]])` would have all floats.

Comment: @Divakar want `4.0` to consider also as a integer, anyways, better if i edit.

Comment: Numpy arrays are homogeneous. All members belong to the same data type. There is no 7 in your array, but there is 7.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rounding:

```
a[np.round(a)!=a] = np.nan
#array([[ 7.,  2.,  4.],
#       [nan, nan,  3.],
#       [nan, nan, nan]])
```

Comment: I have to go out somewhere, so i will accept tomorrow, or remind me :-)

Comment: Wow, got fast back to my computer, just realized that the second row's last element is `3`, i want the whole row to be NaN tho, so the logic is: make the whole row NaN if there's any floats in the row...

Comment: Fixed it: `a[(np.round(a)!=a).any(1)]=np.nan`

Answer (score 1):

`a.dtype==float` returns `True`, hence that doesn't really make any sense. Also, all of your values are floats (you can check this by slicing `type(a[0][0])`.

You could use the `.is_integer` method on floats, but I think `np.mod` will be faster

```
a[np.mod(a, 1) != 0] = np.nan
```